# What should I do if a relevant tag does not yet exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm looking to get help from the community on [polymer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymer), but the tag doesn't yet exist.

Comment: [how-to-add-new-tags-to-code-review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/how-to-add-new-tags-to-code-review)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't worry about it, just ask your question and state that you would like it tagged with "Polymer" and one of the users at Code Review with more reputation can edit your question and add the tag.

You do need to add at least one tag though, so preferably use the language tag that fits best, and any other existing tags that you feel fits your question/code/concern.

Comment: You do need to add at least 1 tag. Perhaps the language can be added as the initial tag.

Comment: Thanks Simon and @Stijn I'll ask the question tagged with [tag:javascript], [tag:html], and [tag:css] normally. Then I will make sure that it should be tagged with [tag:polymer]. I'm really interested in learning about the library, so if there is a Polymer way to do something and I'm not doing it in the Polymer way, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 4):

I've created the [polymer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymer) tag by request, though it may automatically disappear if you don't ask a question within a day.

Comment: Thanks! I'm in the process of creating the question now.